# Why is igraph's cliques() method orders of magnitude slower than justTheCliques?

Tags: algorithm, graph, igraph, clique, clique-problem

I wanted to find all the cliques in a medium size, but densely connected graph, having 369 nodes and 22,724 edges. First I simply called igraph's `Graph.cliques()` method through the python interface:

```
cliques = graph.cliques()
```

It's still running, and consumed more then 3 hours net cpu time on an i7-4600U core. Therefore I started to look after other possibilities, and I remembered a nice code I already used few years before. It is called justTheCliques, and available here: https://github.com/aaronmcdaid/MaximalCliques. The description says:

> runs the Bron-Kerbosch algorithm on an edge list

Running this algorithm gives result on the same graph within a few seconds:

```
justTheCliques edge-list > cliques
```

I love igraph, and I just want to know, what is the essential reason behind this? Igraph uses a different algorithm? The result should be the same?

Comment: In igraph, `graph.cliques()` lists *all* the cliques in the graph, while justTheCliques lists only the *maximal* cliques. If you need the maximal cliques only, use `graph.maximal_cliques()`, which should be just as fast as justTheCliques. The size of the output of `graph.cliques()` is exponentially larger, so no wonder it takes a lot more time to compute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David is right, if you want maximum cliques, then you should use `maximal.cliques()`. I did a quick comparison, and it seems that igraph is in fact 4-5 faster than the C++ library you used, although this probably depends on your graph:

```
library(igraph)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(369, 22724, type="gnm")
system.time(xx <- maximal.cliques(g))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.432   0.012   1.448 
write.graph(g, format = "edgelist", file = "graph.txt")

vagrant@logus:~/cli/MaximalCliques$ time ./justTheCliques graph.txt  > cliques.txt
Network loaded after 0.15 seconds. 369 nodes and 22724 edges. Max degree is 149
processing node: 100 ...
processing node: 200 ...
processing node: 300 ...
388111 cliques found
0   #3
10367   #4
209815  #5
151633  #6
15896   #7
396     #8
4       #9

real    0m6.419s
user    0m5.324s
sys     0m1.036s
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice comparison, then I will use maximal_cliques() of igraph.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though igraph is using an algorithm like [apriori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) for its implementation of `.cliques()`. The 1-cliques are single vertices. The k-cliques are unions of two (k-1)-cliques sharing all but two vertices with an edge between them. I suppose that this algorithm is markedly inferior to Bron--Kerbosch on your graph. If you need only the maximal cliques, it looks as though `.maximal_cliques()` is using a B--K-like algorithm.

Comment: You are correct, igraph's `maximal_cliques()` method uses Bron-Kerbosch so it should be much faster than `cliques()`.

Comment: thank you for explaining this, now I see why does it take much more time